# How to Prove a Grammar is ambiguous? S -> (S)|SS|()

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I am rather new to grammars, and was wondering if someone could help me determine using a parse tree how this grammar below is ambiguous? I know that it needs to have two different strings that can be created.

```
S -> (S)|SS|()
```

I can def convert it to chomsky normal form and greibach, but ambiguity is perplexing to me with these.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to prove a grammar ambiguous is to find a sentence with two different parse trees. (Or two different rightmost derivations, which is exactly the same thing. Or, if you prefer, two different leftmost derivations.)

`S → S S | X` is always ambiguous (for any `X`), because the sentence `X X X` has two different parse trees:

```
         S            S
        / \          / \
       S   S        S   S
      /   / \      / \   \
     X   S   S    S   S   X
         |   |    |   |
         X   X    X   X
```

Comment: The input is correct, but not the trees. You do not have a concatenation in `S` that accepts two `X`. There must be one more level of `S` nodes. Additionally to that, there is no concatenation that accepts `X` and `S` (or `S` and `X`).

Comment: @nikolay: that's true, i condensed the unit productions. Fixed, thanks.